# Get current binding index

Tags: wpf, xaml

My `XAML` code will creates Labels in `WPF window`. How can I  make each `Label`'s Content contain its position rendered from `ItemSource` ?

Currently, the result is: `AAA` `BBB` `CC` ( They are 3 labels )

What I want is: `1` `2` `3` ( They are `3 label` or maybe `0` `1` `2`, because the index base on `0` )

```
<ItemsControl Name="m_Header">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Label Margin="-2,0,0,0" 
               Width="{Binding Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=m_DataGrid}"
               Content="{Binding}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#777" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a DataGrid header. Please note that there is a [DataGridColumn.Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.header.aspx) property,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Index` property defined in the `ItemsControl` class, so there is no way to show that value. However, there is a trick that you can use to get what you want. If your `ItemsControl.AlternationCount` property is set to a suitably high number, then you can use the `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` property to do the same thing for you:

```
<ItemsControl AlternationCount="999"><!--Set this as high as you need-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Label Margin="-2,0,0,0" Width="{Binding Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth, 
ElementName=m_DataGrid}" Content="{(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={
RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="15" Foreground="#777" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you want the numbers to start at a different number, you can add a `Converter` to simply add or subtract the relevant value from each number.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sheridan answer.

Depending on your underlying datasource you might be able use the source count property to set the AlternationCount

**Model**

```
  public class DemoViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<string> Products { get; set; }
  }
```

**Setup DataContext**

```
public MainWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();

      var vm = new DemoViewModel();
      vm.Products = new ObservableCollection<string> { "elm", "oak", "pine" };
      this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
  <ItemsControl AlternationCount="{Binding Products.Count}"
                ItemsSource='{Binding Products}'>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation='Vertical'>
          <Label Margin="2" Width='200'
                 Content="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={
RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                 Foreground="#777" />
          <TextBlock Text='{Binding}' />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All above code work great :).

How to change  `Binding Path=Columns[0]` to `Binding Path=Columns[index_here]`

It's in `Width="{Binding Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth, ElementName=m_DataGrid}"`